# How do you change border line color of wx.StaticBox?

Tags: python, wxpython

[image]

As you can see from the above pic, the border line of wx.StaticBox is always grey on windows, is it possible to change it? I've searched quite a bit, but there doesn't seem to be any properties/attributes for the border line color, so how do you do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question had discussed in [wxPython google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/aZUo4R2rubY). "wx doesn't provide that level of control over the borders of widgets." Robin Dunn. You can try to create new class inherit it from `wx.StaticBox` and implement `OnPaint` method

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! Well, it looks like `wx.StaticBox` is a little bit different from `wx.TextCtrl`, since that grey line is not any kind of border and you cannot really turn it off in styles. But anyway redrawing a new line to cover up the old one is still the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it

> > pnl = wx.Panel()
> >
> > bx1 = wx.StaticBox(pnl, label='Wave 1', pos=(5, 10), size=(300, 500))
> >
> > bx1.SetBackgroundColour((0, 0, 0))

Comment: Good tip..works fine with button borders that you want to inherit their parent's bakground colour